# How do i add some html code after an element in the homepage?

Tags: xml, home

What i want to achieve is that I have some html code in the cms/homepage/design, which I want to insert after a certain element in the homepage. 
This is the xml code:

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sama_productblocks/list" name="sama_productblocks_newproducts" after="call_to_actions" template="sama_productblocks/list.phtml">
                <action method="setIdentifier"><id>homepage-latest</id></action>
            </block>

            <block type="core/template" name="top_banners" before="-" template="homepage/topbanners.phtml">
                <block type="experius_linkmanager/link_list" name="homepage_banner">
                    <action method="setIdentifier"><key>hoesjesoutlet-homepage_banner</key></action>
                </block>
                <block type="experius_linkmanager/link_list" name="homepage_small">
                    <action method="setIdentifier"><key>hoesjesoutlet-homepage_small</key></action>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template" name="cta_banners" after="modelfilter_search" template="homepage/cta.phtml">
                <block type="experius_linkmanager/link_list" name="homepage_cta">
                    <action method="setIdentifier"><key>hoesjesoutlet-homepage_cta</key></action>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template" name="home_text" after="modelfilter_search" template="homepage/text.phtml">
                <!-- Here should I call the html code -->
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```

and the content of the text.phtml should be the html code from the design tab. Well I do not want to remove it from design and put it all of the html code. Is there a function or method  to call the content of design from the homepage ?
This is the content of the template/homepage/text.phtml

```
<div class="cta_row">
    <?php // echo $this->getChildHtml('homepage_text');
    // here i want to put the html code from the design tab from homepage
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your html content inside a new phtml file. This is how you should do it.

File: `app\design\frontend\{your_package}\{your_theme}\template\homepage\my_homepage.phtml`

```
<!-- put your html code inside this file -->
```

ie your html codes comes inside `my_homepage.phtml` template. Now update the last part of your xml code like this.

```
<block type="core/template" name="home_text" after="modelfilter_search" template="homepage/text.phtml">
    <!-- call to your custom html code block -->
    <block type="core/template" name="my.homepage.block" as="homepage_text" template="homepage/my_homepage.phtml" />
</block>
```

Now make sure your `text.phtml` holds this call..

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('homepage_text') ?>
```

Then clear all cache and load the page again. You are done.

### Edit

If you want those html codes editable from admin, then as you have stated in your comment, put those html codes inside  a static block with an identifier `homepage_custom_code` (you can use anything here) and then change your xml code like this.

**Layout update approach**

```
<block type="core/template" name="home_text" after="modelfilter_search" template="homepage/text.phtml">
    <!-- call to your custom html code block -->
    <block type="cms/block" name="my.homepage.sb" as="homepage_text">
         <action method="setBlockId">
               <block_id>homepage_custom_code</block_id>
         </action>
</block>
```

and then call your custom block in `text.phtml` like the same way we did just above ^^^^.

**Hard coding approach** : (I hate this.)

Otherwise call your static block directly inside your `text.phtml` like this.

```
 <?php 
     $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
         'cms/block', 
         'my_custom_text_from_sb', 
          array('block_id' => 'homepage_custom_code')
      )
      ->toHtml() 
  ?>
```

Both way works. But I recommend the first approach. For me, it looks more clear  one.

Comment: I do not want to put the html code inside a phtml file. I want to keep it editable from admin panel. I created a static block a put all of the html code there. then I put the xml code: <block type="core/template" name="home_text" after="modelfilter_search" template="homepage/text.phtml">
            </block>    and after that  in the text.phtml i put this html code and it works: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>. But I am not sure that this is a proper way

Comment: yes you can use that approach definitely. see my update